# Algorithms Python - Difference Between Two Images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In python I am computing the difference between two images uses ImageChops.difference is there a faster way to do this computation? Since it's relatively slow on 720p images, I let it run for about 6 loops, and it took about 30 seconds (using the line_profiler) for analysis.

Comment: Do you want to stick with ImageChops? OpenCV can do what you need and is really good performance-wise.

Comment: Only reason I haven't delved into OCV is the Raspberry camera module I am using isn't well supported on it - but hopefully I'll be able to implement this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy. Put the image data in 2 numpy float arrays, then just do the difference between the two arrays.

Comment: Thanks the seems to have reduced the speed drastically - just have to figure out a faster way to do Image.resize images now.

Comment: You mean, it increased the speed right? It takes less time now ;)